# Android studio emulator UI works but device is different

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio

So I have an app that I am working on that when ran on the emulator it runs perfect. But when I try a device it UI has not updated at all. The code is updated but not the changes to the UI. I don't know what is wrong or even where to look to see why this is happening.

The specific is the colour of 4 buttons that I have. The colour does not change from the pervious version of the app. The code changes for them but not the Button them selves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a long time at working at this I figured out the answer. It was not the emulator/device issues at all. The colour did not change because I need to set the colour of the button via a resource file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
        <stroke
            android:color="@color/black"
            android:width="1dp"
            />
        <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and then do this

```
myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_resource);
```

this fixed the issue of the changing colour of the buttons. I don't know why it would not work with the layout xml file but it did not. The emulator used it just fine. So I don't know if this is not a bug or not. Oh well.
Happy days its fixed.